# Could not found https://github.com/mbanzon/simplehttp golang module. Where it has gone?

Tags: http, go

I was debugging some golang code and found that mbanzon/simplehttp library has been used for http operation but this library does not exist on github anymore.

Is this module became the part of golang core libraries? Any pointers?

Comment: The author removed his repo. Use https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/ instead since it's a built-in package.

Comment: That's why you should ["vendor" your dependencies](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/PackageManagementTools). If you're reluctant at picking any of the package management tools for Go, start with simple subtree merging using Git.

Comment: I'd just drop a letter to @mbanzon politely asking for a snapshot or -- better -- a `git bundle`-d history. I'm sure he has the clone of the original repo somewhere. [Here are the contacts](https://github.com/mbanzon).

Comment: @CodeQuestor I've changed my reply to add some reasoning behind the initial removal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to cause this trouble.

I've found the old code and restored the repository (I don't have the original commits/history so a single commit of the latest state must do).

I hope this helps.

I initially did a sweep to see if anyone *outside* used the library and when I didn't find any I removed it - I now rely on https://github.com/mbanzon/walgo on a day-to-day basis.

The library was originally created to be used with https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-go - changes to that library made `simplehttp` obsolete and I started using the `walgo` library (focusing on request verification etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Do `go get github.com/bmob/goLib/mbanzon/simplehttp`